# use same trigger for different tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to have same trigger name for different tables while inserting new data in MySQL.
Consider X and Y tables.
Both tables have created_date column.

Question is, can I have same single trigger function to effect on both tables while inserting into those tables separately.

> TRIGGER `insert_current_date` BEFORE INSERT ON `X` FOR EACH ROW SET
>   NEW.created_date = NOW( )

This only allow for X table.

For Y table also I need same trigger function.

Is it possible to do with single trigger function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are assigned to specific tables, however, you could create a stored procedure, and run the procedure from the trigger.