# Can we have single trigger for multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can I have a single trigger for multiple tables in MySQL? I have to perform same task after inserting either of the table_1 or table_2 e.g :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger-1_4_task1
   AFTER INSERT ON `table_1`
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    .....task1
   END //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger-2_4_task1
   AFTER INSERT ON `table_2`
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     .... same task as task1
   END //
```

Can I combine two above trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_4_task1
   AFTER INSERT ON `table_1` OR `table_2`
   FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
      ..... task1
     END//
```

Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and have a try. It's called "learning by doing". Or of course you have a look into the official documentation and see in the syntax something that looks like you can specify multiple tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use same trigger for different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811333/use-same-trigger-for-different-tables)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Can I have a single trigger for multiple tables in MySQL?

[No](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).

But multiple triggers could invoke the same [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html).